# Flutter: handle google consent form with automated tests

Tags: google-play-console, firebase-test-lab, google-mobile-ads, flutter-integration-test, admob-cookieconsent

My **Flutter** app is using the **google_mobile_ads** package with the **[Google User Messaging Platform (UMP) SDK](https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/eu-consent#using_the_sdk)** to show a consent form as soon as the app started.
I now want to test my app using:

1. Locally: Flutter integration_test package
2. Google Play: Pre-launch report (Robo scripts)
3. Cloud: Firebase Test Lab (Robo scripts)

#### 1) Flutter integration_test

- With the UMP enabled, I could not find a way to perform a click on the "agree" button or any other element of the consent form using the integration_test package. Interacting with other elements is not a problem.

***Any idea how I can handle the consent form using integration_test package?***

#### 2) Google Play Pre-launch report

- When uploading the app to the Google Play store the pre-launch report using the automated Robo tests shows me 10 screenshots of all possible views of the consent form, but only one screen of my app, which is frustrating.
- The version I upload needs to include the UMP, so there is no way to disable the consent form.
- But I have the option to add/upload a Robo script to *"Testing ->
  Pre-launch report -> Settings -> Control how pre-launch report
  explores your app"*

***What kind of robo script can I add in Google Play console? Any other ways to handle this?***

#### 3) Firebase Test Lab

- Google Play is actually using Firebase Test Lab, so this approach should be the same. With the "Robo tests" option I get the same results as for Google Play, but I could also run custom tests using a "Robo script".
- In the Robo tests -> Crawl graph I could see "ELEMENT_CLICK:Zustimmen" (which means: agree in German)
- Robo scripts examples require a ""resourceId":", what should I put there?

[image]

***Is there a short Robo script I could use to perform this one click?***

---

***TLDR: How can I handle the Google UMP Consent Form in automated test environments using Flutter?***

Answer (score 0):

For pre-launch report and Robo (Roboscript): Besides using resource ID, you can try one of the other element descriptors in your Roboscript to help Robo find the element: https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/robo-scripts-reference#element-descriptors

From that page, you can also try using `visionText` (OCR) descriptions to interact with the element.

This may take some trial and error, since Robo doesn't natively support Flutter. Usually the element's resource ID is a straightforward way to interact with the element, but you may need to set or get this ID specifically for Flutter.